# Motivation to return object or false in PHP

Tags: php, magento, magento2

In the Magento codebase, there are several methods that either return an object or false if the object is not found.

Consider the following example:

```
/**
 * Get block object by name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock|bool
 */
public function getBlock($name)
{
   $this->build();
   if (isset($this->_blocks[$name])) {
      return $this->_blocks[$name];
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

I'm personally confused by this as I would rather return null or throw an exception in some cases.

Is there any specific motivation why this is done in Magento? Is this a general PHP thing?

Comment: i'd guess it's just a matter of personal preference to be able to test the result with `if($result) { $result->doSomething();}`

Comment: I guess, it's the design decision. We do perform null check while playing with objects so in this case we will be doing it like `if ($returnedObject)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bad practice. You have to check the return value at caller, so method chaining is impossible.

I personally tend to have a separate check method in such cases and have the getter throw an exception on error. Such as:

```
public function hasBlock($name) {
    return isset($this->_blocks[$name]);
}

public function getBlock($name) {
    if (!$this->hasBlock($name)) {
        throw new \LogicException("No block of name $name.");
    }
    return $this->_blocks[$name];
}
```

This way you can always expect a single type return value from `getBlock()` and thus have methods chained like `$obj->getBlock("name")->doStuff()`.

The type of exception depends on the context. I think `LogicException` is appropriate here since it's a programming error not to check that given block exists before using it.

Of course you could skip checking the block existence and have `RuntimeError` or such thrown and handle those at upper level in your application logic.